# Install Campaign Tracking for Ionic V3 apps

Tags: ionic3

Can someone please help me out with the process to set up Google Play Store campaign tracking for Ionic/Cordova app with Google Analytics/Firebase analytics plugin in such a way that UTM parameters flow to Google Analytics/Firebase analytics without a problem.

Comment: Did you manage to find a way to track campaigns? I'm looking for the same (but ionic v5), it's not that easy as one may think..

Comment: same here, being struggling for days without any luck